# How To Use Ampersand (&) Symbol For a Label In Symbology 10.2?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, symbology

I am using unique values to symbolize my data. I am changing the labels as needed so they are reflected in my table of contents. I want to label one category "Oil & Gas". However when I use the ampersand (&) in the label, it becomes an underscore "_".

Any thoughts on how to keep the ampersand?
[image]

Comment: Also, on 10.2 Help, it says there is a "Format Label" option, but this does not appear as the documentation states. http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s50000001p000000

Comment: If you review that section of the help page you linked to, you'll note it only applies to formatting numeric fields (ie number appearance).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer may be **dont**, it's a special character.

You can put an ampersand in your layer name that looks just great in ArcMap:

[image]

Using a double ampersand `&&`:

[image]

But when you create a map of it:

[image]

The legend gets expanded to the 'true' text.

Comment: That worked! (I don't need a legend so it works perfectly for my purposes).